# How to Pass Variable inside DQL CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, doctrine

i got a question in DQL how to pass session User id

```
$vars['mood'] = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select(’m.mood_name, a.id, m.account_id’)
->from(’mood m, m.account a’)
->where(’m.account_id=”7″‘)
```

i want to show data according to current logged user.

```
m.account_id=Current_User::user()->id;
```

this is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Session Values in CodeIgniter

[The documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) indicates that if you wish to extract a value from the session, you ought to use the following syntax:

```
$this->load->library("session");
/*...*/
$userid = $this->session->userdata("userid");
```

#### WHERE Clause in Doctrine

According to the [DQL Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language#where-clause), we need only patch that into your `where` statement:

```
->where("m.account_id = ?", $userid)
```

Comment: I m getting doctrine Error


  $userid = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
        $vars['mood'] = Doctrine_Query::create()
 ->select('m.mood_name, a.id, m.account_id')
 ->from('mood m, m.account a')
 ->where('m.account_id=$userid')
 ->execute();

Comment: after adding ->where("m.account_id = ?", $userid);

i m getting  Parse error

Comment: Make sure you have a valid reference to `session` before trying to use `$this->session`

Comment: i changed it to ->where('m.account_id = ?', $userid);

Comment: tht workgin when i m adding using same to add current logged user id
but not inside DQL

Comment: Is your session library loaded, Ansh?

Comment: Yes i m able to add User_id from Session to mysql.
using this  $u->account_id = Current_User::user()->id;

Comment: ->where('m.account_id = ?','$userid'); i tried this is also not working as shown in Documentation.

Comment: Solved I  need to remove ; in WHERE lol Thanks Alot Jonathan u always help me :) Have a nice day